If there is not energy loss will a circuit board do the same processes forever with the initial energy?
same as above. if we for example take a circuit board of laptop without any speakers or screen just the circuit board and if we can stop energy loss from this can it do the same process forever with the charge which was initially inside the battery?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle

I suppose the circuit board just sitting there without any power is doing the same processes forever...

@RileyScottJacob Arguably, you don't even need Landauer's principle to answer this question in the negative: Computers move charges around, which requires work, and thus the expenditure of energy. While Landauer's principle provides a lower bound for the energy needed from an information theory viewpoint, the fact that computation is a physical task that requires a system to change its state means that there is necessarily energy consumption involved. This question essentially asks about a perpetuum mobile, which is well known to be impossible.

You are essentially asking if a perpetuum mobile is possible. Computational processes inside a modern digital computer are realized by charges moving around, which is a process that requires work to be done, and thus requires energy. That being said, even if you managed to "stop energy loss", you would essentially turn your hypothetical computer into a closed thermodynamical system, in which entropy can only increase, thus making any useful computations impossible once a certain threshold is reached.

Theoretically, a circuit board could do the same process indefinitely without any energy losses (although it would be completely pointless) there are several conditions that would have to be met. For example, all components would have to have no resistance and it would need to be insulated perfectly so that no energy could be dissipated to the surroundings as heat etc. Real-world limitations make this physically impossible.


if we for example take a circuit board of laptop without any speakers or screen just the circuit board and if we can stop energy loss from this

If the laptop circuit board has a microprocessor that is doing some calculations, then we can not stop the energy loss while continuing to do the calculations. Each calculation a microprocessor does transfers charge through logic gates, and this process consumes energy (actually, converts electrical potential energy in to heat).

... can it do the same process forever with the charge which was initially inside the battery.

If you mean the process of calculating things in the microprocessor, then no, it can't.
If you wait until the battery is depleted and the board is just sitting there not doing any calculations or otherwise moving charge through its circuits, and its temperature has come into equilibrium with its surroundings after dissipating the heat produced by the calculations it did previously, then yes it can continue doing that indefinitely.
